# A charge $Q$ is placed at a distance $a/2$ above the center of a horizontal square surface of edge $a$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> A  charge $Q$ is placed at  $a$ distance $a/2$ above the center of a horizontal square surface of edge $a$, while a second charge $Q$ is placed below one of the vertices of square. Find the flux of the electric field through the square.

ATTEMPT:

The flux due to the charge Q at distance $a/2$ will be **$Q/6 ε$** while that due to other charge Q at a distance $a$ Will be **$ Q/24ε$**. So the total flux will be the sum of two.

But in text it is as given the difference. Why?

I think it is associated with the direction of outward normal to surface.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two arrangements of charges:

[image: Flux through surface]

Suppose we ask what is the flux through the surface $S$. If you look at figure (a) with two positive charges the flux lines from the two charges travel in opposing directions and will cancel each other out at $S$. So the flux through $S$ will be the flux from one charge **minus** the flux from the other charge. Since the system is symmetrical about the surface the flux will be zero.

If you look at figure (b) with a positive charge and a negatvie charge, the flux lines are all travelling in the same direction so they reinforce. The flux through $S$ will be the flux from the charge $+Q$ **plus** the flux from the charge $-Q$, and the net flux will be non-zero.

This is what is happening in your example. Since your two charges have the same sign, the flux lines from them are travelling in opposing directions and will partially cancel. So you get the net flux by subtracting the two fluxes. If you changed one of your charges from $Q$ to $-Q$ then you would add the fluxes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not sum because its at different sides of the surface. So flux made by one will be cancelling the other partially. So taking the difference is correct. 
Had the question been both charges above the surface taking sum is perfect.

Comment: @yasir you can answer your own question too so considering my hint give your own proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The outward area vector convention we use is for closed surfaces. (For example a cube). For non-closed surfaces, the net flux would be the flux through one side subtracted from the flux through the other.

A somewhat weak analogy would be forces on a body. If there is a force directed towards the left, and one towards the right, (on the same body, of course) the net force would be the difference of these, and in the direction of the greater force. Some part of the forces cancels out, and same goes for the flux. (in this case.)

Comment: what if i had a cube in place of the square sheet, with the two charges still below and above the cube? will the flux cancel there also?

Comment: Ah, there, the net flux itself would be zero. because the cube doesn't enclose both the charges! (Gauss's law.)